# How to do 'select count(distinct column) from table' with jpa query method?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to do `select count(distinct column1) from table` with jpa query method not with query annotation?

I know I can do `select count(distinct column1) from table where column2 = :column2` by `long countDistinctColumn1ByColumn2(:column2)`.

I've searched official documents and tried some tests but couldn't find a way, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Spring Data JPA.

The documentation can be found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods

Comment: I've seen that documentation, but couldn't find any clue. Could you tell me the exact point where the documentation says that?

Comment: There is no countDistinct it list